# Convert columns into rows in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables with same structure. One table contains old value and another table contains new value of all columns. I want to get out out as columns as 1 column and old and new value row wise with changed value of columns.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    Column1 varchar(100) NULL,
    Column2 varchar(100) NULL,
    Column3 varchar(100) NULL
);

INSERT INTO webtest.test
(Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES('1', '2', '3');

CREATE TABLE test_hist (
    Column1 varchar(100) NULL,
    Column2 varchar(100) NULL,
    Column3 varchar(100) NULL
);

INSERT INTO test
(Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES('1', '3', '4');
```

I want output like below:

```
| Field_Name | Old_Value| | New_Value|
| -------- | -------- |  
| Column2   | 2       |    4
| Column3   | 3       |    5
```

any help would be highly appreciated. thanks in advance.

I tried to use pivot but that is not available in mysql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about union of joins?

```
select 'column 1' as col_nm, b.column1 as old_val, a.column1 as new_val
  from test a join test_hist b on a.column1 <> b.column1
union all
select 'column 2'          , b.column2           , a.column2
  from test a join test_hist b on a.column2 <> b.column2
union all
select 'column 3'          , b.column3           , a.column3
  from test a join test_hist b on a.column3 <> b.column3;
```

For sample data you posted, result is

```
col_nm    old_val  new_val
--------  -------  -------
column 2  3        2
column 3  4        3
```

Have a look at the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lnhUeoQV) that illustrates it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in my table there more than 30 columns and here i will have to write 30 union statement for each column

Comment: @Lavkushkumar can you write a dynamic query in mysql?

Comment: Converted above query to dynamic.. https://dbfiddle.uk/_pf_yeWJ

Comment: thanks @jakbar I have tried this but unable to figure out the way where some id is bening stored from some another table and referenced as foreign key. dynamically I m unable to do .In output i want the original value not the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `subqueries` and `UNION`.

```
SELECT Field_Name, Old_Value, New_Value
FROM (
    SELECT 'Column1' AS Field_Name,
           (SELECT Column1 FROM test WHERE (SELECT Column1 FROM test_hist) <> Column1 LIMIT 1) AS Old_Value,
           (SELECT Column1 FROM test_hist) AS New_Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Column2' AS Field_Name,
           (SELECT Column2 FROM test WHERE (SELECT Column2 FROM test_hist) <> Column2 LIMIT 1) AS Old_Value,
           (SELECT Column2 FROM test_hist) AS New_Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Column3' AS Field_Name,
           (SELECT Column3 FROM test WHERE (SELECT Column3 FROM test_hist) <> Column3 LIMIT 1) AS Old_Value,
           (SELECT Column3 FROM test_hist) AS New_Value
) AS Result
WHERE Old_Value IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks @amit for ur reply but in this solution there is one issue in my table there are more than 30 columns so for each column I will have to write union